# How do I paste multi-line python script into ConEmu?

Tags: python, windows-10, copy-paste, git-bash

Is it possible to copy and paste muti-line python into Git Bash? (in Windows 10)

Currently, if I have Python in Sublime text

[image]

when I paste it into Git Bash (I'm running Git Bash inside ConEmu), the line breaks are ignored.

[image]

I know about execfile(), but in my case I need to be able to be able see both the pasted code and result.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just do like a split screen setup

Comment: Well, this is for class, and I'm frequently asked to copy and paste (it works fine in teminal on Macs, which my instructor uses). I also have to submit console transcripts for assignments. I know it's a weird situation.

Answer (score 11):

ConeMu has [two paste modes](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsPaste.html)

Instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>v</kbd> (paste mode #1) you can use paste mode #2 by

- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> or
- `right click`